# How to display pivot Table on webgrid in MVC

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to display monthly employee attendance. So I have created a stored procedure that adds dynamic columns using a pivot table. I don't know how to access the pivot columns. Hence I cannot create a class with dynamic number of fields as data source.

**Stored procedure**

```
ALTER procedure [dbo].[sps_AttendanceShow] @mon int, @year int As
begin DECLARE @cols  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)=''; DECLARE @query AS
NVARCHAR(MAX)='';

SELECT @cols = @cols + QUOTENAME(AttendaceDate) + ',' FROM (  select 
e.Name,a.WorkHours,a.AttendaceDate from  Attendace a,employee e where
e.EmpID=a.EmpID AND MONTH(a.AttendaceDate)=@mon AND
YEAR(a.AttendaceDate)=@year) as temp3 select @cols = substring(@cols,
0, len(@cols)) 

set @query =  'SELECT * from  (
    select  e.Name,a.WorkHours,a.AttendaceDate from  Attendace a,employee e where e.EmpID=a.EmpID  ) src pivot  (
    max(WorkHours) for AttendaceDate in (' + @cols + ') ) piv'

execute(@query) end
```

And the results as given below:

[image]